# Microsoft Video API Sample not working

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I use Microsoft Video API https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Video-Windows and run a WPF Form with subscription key.
But after upload a mp4 with only 2 mb (5seconds), it never return result but only with the following status:

```
[22:23:29.247832]: [Motion Detection] Start motion detection
[22:23:29.268208]: [Motion Detection] Start uploading video
[22:23:33.763941]: [Motion Detection] Uploading video done
[22:23:34.421370]: [Motion Detection] Server status: Running, wait 20 seconds...
[22:23:56.411876]: [Motion Detection] Server status: Running, wait 20 seconds...
[22:24:16.897360]: [Motion Detection] Server status: Running, wait 20 seconds...
[22:24:37.101580]: [Motion Detection] Server status: Running, wait 20 seconds...
[22:24:57.593576]: [Motion Detection] Server status: Running, wait 20 seconds...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Cognitive video API calls (and possibly others) are not working at all today. There was a thread here on SO stating global issues Azure was facing, but it was pulled.

Really hoping that someones' video got stuck in the queue and will be flushed in 24 hours. Understanding that a lot of the APIs are still in "Preview" mode, but this sort of downtime really requires an explanation with fix ETA from Microsoft.